# My apps despite being published in Google Play are not visible in search

Tags: search, publishing, visible

i uploaded my apps in Google Play and despite them being all published, they are still not visible in search unless you search for its exact name. It was about a week ago.

There is 15 of them. Full name of one of them is "TalkPhone German Basics".

If I search "TalkPhone" it works. It finds.

If I search "German" it is nowhere on the list.

Same thing happens to every other language (each app - other language).

Can you please suggest what might be the reason to that?

Comment: Some interesting info on how apps are ranked in the Google Play store http://simlabs.submitinme.com/seo-for-google-andriod-market-aka-google-play-a-case-study/

Comment: Please stop adding links to other peoples answers via suggested edits. It looks **a lot** like SPAM.

Answer (score 0):

If you search "German" there is thousands of other apps. If you just have a very few downloads, your app will take some time to scroll down to. Play Market makes it easier to find the apps with the most downloads.

You may also have translateted your description and app name from your developer console.

Comment: 1. I scrolled all the list down. Not only on German but on Spanish and Russian versions too. Took me a while but it did it.

2. I have no downloads.

3. What do you mean translated? I didn't translate it. Its in english both description and title.

Comment: I think some of the results are not shown because there are over a 1000 apps containing german in the title or in description. If you get more downloads, your app will be more visible.

Comment: Ok I will try getting some outside traffic into that. Thanks